# How get get Failover cluster volume information using powershell?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, failovercluster

The screenshot below is Win2012R2 Failover Cluster Volume. Those volumes are mapped from SAN through FC connection.
I am trying to get this volume information as shown in screenshot by using powershell.

But I dont see there is any command for getting what I want.

I have tried "Get-ClusterResource", "Get-Cluster", "Get-ClusterDisk" as well as "Get-ClusterSharedVolume" which returns nothing.

Any idea how?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For CSVFS you can use next command in PowerShell:

```
Get-Volume | where {$_.FileSystem -match "CSVFS"} | fl *
```

for regular NTFS + Quorum this one

```
Get-ClusterResource | where {$_.ResourceType -eq "Physical Disk"} | fl *
```

Please note that this commands should be run inside cluster member.